# How to Insert an Excel workbook into another Excel workbook range

Tags: excel, object, insert, vba

I need to insert one Excel workbook into another Excel workbook, always at the same range address of the 2nd workbook.  I have seen the "Selection.InsertFile" method,but how can I make that specific range the selection?

I tried:

```
JDT.Sheets("Document Template").Range("E44").Select
Selection.InsertFile Filename:=Path & Fname
```

but got:"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: You're trying to put an entire Excel workbook into a single cell?

Comment: No, I realized I needed to insert an Object - the Excel workbook - probably using OLE with which I was unfamiliar, but I found some script and adapted it to my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was inserting an object, so that I probably had to use OLE, with which I was unfamiliar.  I found and adapted an answer into my macro yesterday, but forgot to come back and post it, so thanks for the "reminder" to post it for the benefit of others:

```
'Inserts the Backup Template file into the JDT file

For Each cell In JDT.Sheets("Document Template").Range("E44")
If IsEmpty(cell) Then
    Dim ol As OLEObject
    Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=Path & Fname,   
    Link:=False,     DisplayAsIcon:=True, Height:=2)
   With ol
    .Top = cell.Offset(0, 1).Top
    .Left = cell.Offset(0, 1).Left
   End With
  End If
Next
```

I realize a For-Next Loop to target 1 cell is inefficient, but it gave me cell oriented statements that were useful, so having already spent too much time on this, I moved on to the next challenge.